# Not all Groups are returned via WMI

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

Using the code below not all Group names are returned if I compare to computer management. Am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE: It does update if i restart my application**

**C# Code**

```
try
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
        new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
        "SELECT * FROM Win32_GroupUser");            

    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
    {   
         String sGroupName = queryObj["GroupComponent"].ToString().Split(new[] { "Name=" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Last().Trim('"'); 
         String sUsername = queryObj["PartComponent"].ToString().Split(new[] { "Name=" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Last().Trim('"');
    }
}
catch (ManagementException exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + exception.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was binding the results to a grid and you have to set the datasource to null first - this was my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Win32_GroupUser is a relationship between users and groups.

If a group has no users, it will not be included.

Try querying for Win32_Group.

Comment: i added a user and the group doesnt get added - maybe i have to reboot?

Comment: Actually i just figured out it does update when i restart my application which is strange